# Find translation and rotation of a 3D image given a 2D projection

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

Given a non-planar 3D image and a 2D projection image, I need to determine the 3D translation and rotation of the 3D image that led to the 2D projection.

I have 3D coordinates of a 3D image and some of the corresponding 2D coordinates of the 2D image. I would like to find the translation and rotation of the 3D image that would best match the x and y coordinates of the 2D image. Also, the scale between the 3D image and 2D image is unknown. The 3D image is in mm, but the 2D image is in pixels.

Is there some matlab code or a set of formulas that shows how to get the translation and rotation of the 3D image to match the 2D projection?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is known as the PnP problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective-n-Point

Comment: And the Wikipedia article even links to MATLAB code for [EPnP by Lepetit et al. (2009)](https://cvlab.epfl.ch/EPnP/index.php).

Comment: There's even a [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimateworldcamerapose.html) for it in the Computer Vision Toolbox.

Comment: Can this be solved without knowing the camera parameters?

Comment: @beaker nice! You should add this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what kind of projection is used.

In general case you have projection matrix T with unknown coefficients T<sub>ij</sub>, set of source coordinates S[], set of result projections P[] and set of equations for every S-P pair:

```
S * T = P
```

Try to solve this equation system for matrix coefficients.

[Example math for 2D case](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ph/texfund/texfund.pdf)

Comment: More than probably a central projection. The system of equations is highly nonlinear.